# Finding rows where totals do not match

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join

MariaDB MySQL

Trying to do what seems like a basic query (join) on two tables.

**Receipts**

| id | date | supplier | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

**Parts**

| id | receipt_id | partType | subtotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Trying to get the row from the first table when the totals of subtotal of each `parts.receipt_id` does not equal `receipts.id.total`.

My butchered attempts include:

```
SELECT `receipts`.*
FROM `receipts` 
LEFT JOIN ON `receipts`.`id`=`parts`.`receipt_id` 
WHERE SUM(`parts`.`subtotal`) != `receipts`.`total` 
GROUP BY `parts`.`receipt_id`;
```

Current work around using compare in PHP (very inefficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subqueries as long they only return 1 Value (row)

```
SELECT 
    r.*
FROM
    receipts r
WHERE
    (SELECT 
            SUM(parts.subtotal)
        FROM
            parts
        WHERE
            receipt_id = r.id) != r.total;
```

This works as you can see.

If your data have another design, pleae provide a changed dbfille

> ```
> CREATE TABLE receipts (id  int,   `date`date,     supplier varchar(10),   total DECIMAL(10,2))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO receipts VALUES (1,NOW(),'a',100.1),(2,NOW(),'b',200.2)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE parts (id    int, receipt_id     int , partType varchar(10),     subtotal DECIMAL(10,2))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO parts VALUEs (1,1,'a',20.0),(2,1,'a',20.0),(3,1,'a',20.1),(4,1,'a',20.0),(2,1,'a',20.0),
> (6,2,'a',50.0),(7,2,'a',150.0)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     r.*
> FROM
>     receipts r
> WHERE
>     (SELECT 
>             SUM(parts.subtotal)
>         FROM
>             parts
>         WHERE
>             receipt_id = r.id) != r.total;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | supplier |  total
> -: | :--------- | :------- | -----:
>  2 | 2021-06-17 | b        | 200.20
> ```

> ```
>  SELECT 
>     r.* ,  (SELECT 
>             SUM(parts.subtotal)
>         FROM
>             parts
>         WHERE
>             receipt_id = r.id) sumsubtotal
>  FROM
>     receipts r
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date       | supplier |  total | sumsubtotal
> -: | :--------- | :------- | -----: | ----------:
>  1 | 2021-06-17 | a        | 100.10 |      100.10
>  2 | 2021-06-17 | b        | 200.20 |      200.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6117b1200934e6cd0589ccc7897be665)*

Comment: Will likely return more than one row from the first table, certainly in testing, but thank you for the idea. I don't need any rows from the second table nbk

Comment: Tried your suggestion, no results returned.

Comment: With = r.total it does return all the receipts that a totalled correctly. So just have to figure out how to negate the whole query.

Comment: @Xander please make  a https://dbfiddle.uk  and i will see what the error is

Comment: Indead it does work, I missed the reassignment of "receipt" to "r". Very nice!!!
Is there a way I could show total of receipt - total of parts.subtotal?

Comment: Ignore me I see you have covered that in you last query, thank you.

Comment: The second function hits everything on the nose, thank you NBK.
As a new user I cannot upvote you :,(

Comment: yes but you can accept the answer see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you Sir o7